# How to call overridden base class method using C++/CLI

Tags: .net, c++-cli

What is the proper way to implement this C# code:

```
protected override void SomeMethod(inputs)  
{  
    ... do stuff ..  
    base.SomeMethod(inputs);  
}
```

in C++/CLI

Comment: Please don't use `<code>` tags. Formatting help is available in the post editing view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By qualifiying the method name with base class name.

```
void SomeMethod(inputs)
{
    ... do stuff ..
    base::SomeMethod(inputs);
}
```

**[Online Demo:](http://ideone.com/clone/jr3rL)**

```
#include<iostream>
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void doSomething()
    {
        std::cout<<"In Base";
    }
};

class Derived:public Base
{
public:
    virtual void doSomething()
    {
        std::cout<<"In Derived";
        Base::doSomething();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base *ptr = new Derived;
    ptr->doSomething();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Also, do not forget to `delete ptr` as I did in the above program.

Comment: Note: The questioner tells `base.SomeMethod(inputs);` where the `base` is a C# keyword not the name of the base class.